# Generator to read lines from file

Tags: python, file, generator

Is there any advantage of using a generator function to read lines from a file? I'm asking this because I saw something like this in a script:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    liter = (l.rstrip("\r\n") for l in f)  # <generator object <genexpr> at 0x10617c728>
    for line in liter:
```

Would this approach be better (or in what circumstances) than a simple block like:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip("\r\n")
```

Comment: it has no advantages, unless you can write your code in 1 line using chained generator comprehensions.

Comment: note that you don't need to `rstrip(`\r")` as text mode does that already.

Comment: For one, I wouldn't shadow the built-in `iter` function with your variable name. Use `it` or better yet, something descrpitive like `stripped_lines`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sure, my mistake, the code was actually `liter =`. Corrected in question.

Comment: `liter` isn't very good choice for other reasons :) it"s mispelled synonym for "garbage" :)

Comment: I believe generators use a LOT less memory. If you had a huge CSV file (eg millions of rows) to process in Python, it would probably grind to a halt if you didn't use a generator.

Comment: @MatthewDaly That would make sense as the idea is to read potential big files. But even with the second approach wouldn't you be iterating line by line i.e. not reading the whole file into memory?

Comment: @PedroA I'd suggest looking at https://scottmoonen.com/2008/02/01/python-generators-saving-time-and-memory/ for details, but iterating over the lines doesn't necessarily mean the old ones are clesned up. PHP has similar generators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first approach doesn't bring much:

- it is not a full comprehension syntax since there's a loop
- it is not a full loop code (so beginners will have a hard time understanding it)

It would have an interest if you could write your code in one line *without* the loop:

```
result = [x for x in (l.rstrip("\n") for l in f) if x]
```

(creating a list of non-empty lines, that is, and as a side note, you don't have to strip `\r` from the end of line because text mode already does it, unless of course there are more than 1 `\r` character, which is non-standard)

Or in a `lambda` that you would use all over your code to avoid forgetting removing those damn linefeeds:

```
stripped_lines = lambda f : (l.rstrip("\n") for l in f)
```

then

```
for l in stripped_lines(f):
   ...
```

The second approach is clearer and simpler *if* you have to use a loop (if you have side-effect calls, it's recommended to avoid comprehensions and use loops instead)